# How to load data with AJAX on document Load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i am new to AJAX and jQuery i don't know how to load data with ajax in modal with jQuery.

I am just using the

```
(document).ready(function () {( 
)};
```

By using this my code in the `document.ready` function is placed in unbind way.

I am searching for best way to make Modal more accurate using AJAX.

CODE :

```html
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    //*** function to getmaxcode of voucher type from database
    function getMaxCodeForVoucherType(urlStr, VrType) {
      if (VrType !== "") {
        $.ajax({
          url: urlStr,
          type: "GET",
          data: { VoucherTypeId: VrType },
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function (response) {
            //***Generate Options Via Ajax Response
            var elemVoucherTypeTypeCode = $('#voucherCode');
            elemVoucherTypeTypeCode.val('');
            if (response.Success === true) {

              var maxCode = response.Data.voucherMaxCode;
              elemVoucherTypeTypeCode.val(maxCode);

            }
            //alert(output);
          },
          error: function (response) {
            console.log("No record Found");
          },

        });
      }
    }

    //**Fetching the record for cash accounts from database
    var DOCUMENT =  $("#modal_backdropCashVoucher");
    $(DOCUMENT).load(function () {
      var debitAccounts = $("#DACC");
      var url = "@Url.Action("GetAllDetailedCashAccounts", "Vouchers")";
      var urlStr1 = "@(Url.Action("GetMaxCodeByVoucherTypeId", "Vouchers"))";
      $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: url,
        dataType: 'json',
        data:{},
        success: function (response) {

          debitAccounts.html('<option value=""></option>');
          if (response.Success === true) {
            for (i in response.DataSet) {
              if (response.DataSet.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
                debitAccounts.append('<option value="' + response.DataSet[i].Id + '">' + response.DataSet[i].Name + '</option>');
              }
            }

          }
        },
        cache: false
      });
      getMaxCodeForVoucherType(urlStr1, 2);

      //  }); // end voucher types changing mode

      //*** START -------- Credit Account behavour

      var allCashAccounts = $("#creditAccount");
      var url = "@Url.Action("GetAllDetailedAccounts", "Vouchers")";
      $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: url,
        dataType: 'json',
        data:{},
        success: function (response) {

          allCashAccounts.html('<option value=""></option>');
          if (response.Success === true) {
            for (i in response.DataSet) {
              if (response.DataSet.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
                allCashAccounts.append('<option value="' + response.DataSet[i].Id + '">' + response.DataSet[i].Name + '</option>');
              }
            }

          }
        },
        cache: false
      });

      //*** END -------- Credit Account behavour
 //========================================================================
      //=====END=======Dynamic behaviour of voucehr on voucher type ==========
      //========================================================================
    });
  });//eFuntionnding main 
</script>
```

I want do this thing in a better way please give me a Path to move in right direction.

Comment: When do you want the data loaded in the modal? When it is opened? What modal framework are you using?

Comment: What server side language are you using? If php you can just define the variables in an included php script, then pull them in with the defined name.

Comment: @epascarello when i call the modal on click the data must be loaded into the modal when i take the look of it...i am using EF(Entity Framework)  in ASP.NET .

Comment: @Geoff Asp.Net and Entity Framework i am using